# Оставить только строку заданной длины в файле в php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, файлы

Как оставить только строку заданной длины в файле?

```
$replaced=preg_replace("(\b((\S{0,8}))\b)", "",$replaced );
```

Comment: Если прямо конкретной длины то `mb_substr`, а если же это нужно сделать именно с помощью `регулярного выражения` то так и пишите в постановке вопроса

Comment: надо чтоб осталась только та (те) строка которая состоит из 5 символов.
до
333
4444
55555
666666 

после
55555

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что на вход у Вас есть строка вида `333 4444 55555 666666` состоящая из набора символов разной длины отделенных друг от друга пробелом и из этой строки Вам необходимо оставить только те наборы символов которые имеют длину в 5 символов?

Comment: Приведите пример, в вопросе нажав кнопку "парвить", валидной строки и не валидной, пока не понятно из вопроса ничего, `^.{25}$` в матч отберет только строки состоящие из 25 символов

Answer (score 0):

С помощью регулярного выражения

```php
$str = "333 4444 55555 666666";
preg_match_all("/(\b\S{5}\b)/", $str, $matches);
var_dump( $matches );
```

> результат

> array(2) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [0] =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      array(1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [0] =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      string(5) "55555"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           [1] =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      array(1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [0] =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      string(5) "55555"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         }
> }

Без регулярного выражения

```php
$str = "333 4444 55555 666666";
$words = explode(" ", $str);
foreach( $words as $word ) {
    if ( mb_strlen( $word ) == 5 ) {
        echo $word."\n";
    }
}
```

Хотя зачем я тут все это пишу, опять же набегут тролли, наставят минусов без объяснения причин...

Comment: `$str = ($replaced);
$words = explode(" ", $str);
foreach( $words as $word ) {
    if ( mb_strlen( $word ) == 9 ) {
        echo $word."\n";
    }
}`

не сработал :(

Comment: значит в строке нет под-строк из 9 -и символов